# error in SQL syntax, invalid syntax

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT s0_.id, s0_.caption, s0_.lowresimageurl, s0_.medresimageurl, s0_.highresimageurl, s0_.price
FROM app_instagram_shop_picture s0_
LEFT JOIN app_instagram_shop s1_ force index (idx_locked_deletedAt)
LEFT JOIN app_instagram_picture_category s2_
LEFT JOIN app_instagram_first_level_category s3_
ON s0_.shop_id = s1_.id 
AND s1_.deletedAt IS NULL
AND s0_.id = s2_.picture_id
AND s2_.first_level_category_id = s3_.id
WHERE (s0_.isShown = 1
AND s1_.id != 32179
AND s1_.expirydate IS NULL
AND s1_.deletedAt IS NULL
AND s1_.isLocked = 0
AND s1_.owner_id IS NULL 
AND s0_.id != 2598561
AND s0_.deletedAt IS NULL
AND s0_.isStyleInspiration = 0 
AND s0_.isLocked = 0 
AND s3_.id = 11 
) 
AND (s0_.deletedAt IS NULL) 
ORDER BY s0_.updated DESC 
LIMIT 16
```

for some reason this is causing me an error of following:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE (s0_.isShown = 1
AND s1_.id != 32179
AND s1_.expirydate IS N' at line 10
```

however, I can't seem to figure out what the issue is..

Comment: What are the brackets there for?

Comment: Does your join work once you remove everything from `WHERE` onwards? I think you need to specify the join condition before you move to the next table join statement.

Comment: You missed condition in ON clause in JOIN for s1_ and s2_ tables

Answer (score 0):

Remember to only have one WHERE clause per SELECT statement and to use it at the very beginning of your checks and thereafter only use AND's (I have been caught myself many times by forgetting this and placing extra WHERE clauses later in a chain)

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT s0_.id, s0_.caption, s0_.lowresimageurl, s0_.medresimageurl, s0_.highresimageurl,                          s0_.price
FROM app_instagram_shop_picture s0_
LEFT JOIN app_instagram_shop s1_ force index (idx_locked_deletedAt)
LEFT JOIN app_instagram_picture_category s2_
LEFT JOIN app_instagram_first_level_category s3_
ON s0_.shop_id = s1_.id 
AND s1_.deletedAt IS NULL
AND s0_.id = s2_.picture_id
AND s2_.first_level_category_id = s3_.id
WHERE s0_.isShown = 1
AND s1_.id != 32179
AND s1_.expirydate IS NULL
AND s1_.deletedAt IS NULL
AND s1_.isLocked = 0
AND s1_.owner_id IS NULL 
AND s0_.id != 2598561
AND s0_.deletedAt IS NULL
AND s0_.isStyleInspiration = 0 
AND s0_.isLocked = 0 
AND s3_.id = 11 

AND s0_.deletedAt IS NULL
ORDER BY s0_.updated DESC 
LIMIT 16
```

Answer (score 0):

With [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html), you need to specify either `ON` or `USING` for each table joined to indicate the join relationship.

You have 3 `LEFT JOINs` but only one `ON` condition. You may have intended this:

```
FROM app_instagram_shop_picture s0_
  LEFT JOIN app_instagram_shop s1_ force index (idx_locked_deletedAt)
  ON s0_.shop_id = s1_.id 
  AND s1_.deletedAt IS NULL
  LEFT JOIN app_instagram_picture_category s2_
  ON s0_.id = s2_.picture_id
  LEFT JOIN app_instagram_first_level_category s3_
  ON s2_.first_level_category_id = s3_.id
```

(Specifying additional predicates in the first `ON s0_.shop_id = s1_.id` will not work for the other join tables)

Answer (score 0):

Bracket my causes error please remove bracket and use it

```
SELECT s0_.id, s0_.caption, s0_.lowresimageurl, s0_.medresimageurl, s0_.highresimageurl, s0_.price
FROM app_instagram_shop_picture s0_
LEFT JOIN app_instagram_shop s1_ force index (idx_locked_deletedAt)
LEFT JOIN app_instagram_picture_category s2_
LEFT JOIN app_instagram_first_level_category s3_
ON s0_.shop_id = s1_.id 
AND s1_.deletedAt IS NULL
AND s0_.id = s2_.picture_id
AND s2_.first_level_category_id = s3_.id
WHERE s0_.isShown = 1
AND s1_.id != 32179
AND s1_.expirydate IS NULL
AND s1_.deletedAt IS NULL
AND s1_.isLocked = 0
AND s1_.owner_id IS NULL 
AND s0_.id != 2598561
AND s0_.deletedAt IS NULL
AND s0_.isStyleInspiration = 0 
AND s0_.isLocked = 0 
AND s3_.id = 11 

AND (s0_.deletedAt IS NULL) 
ORDER BY s0_.updated DESC 
LIMIT 16
```